# Efficient ways to combine multiple .csv files using python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, parallel-processing

I currently have about 700 '.csv' files and want to combine them into one. Each file has three columns: 'date', 'time' and 'var'. I have to combine them based on two columns: date and name. I currently read them as dataframe. After combining them, the final file should have columns of date, name, var1, var2,var3...var700. I currently use pandas merge function, but it is supper slow, as the data is large. Is there any efficient way to combine the files? My current code is as follows:

```
for filename in os.listdir(signal_path):
    filepath=os.path.join(signal_path,filename)
    _temp = pd.read_pickle(filepath)
    data.merge(_temp, how = 'left', on=['date','name'])
```

I have attached a 
[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRwfd.png)    , each file has different length.

Comment: Where does the column 'name' come from, and are the timestamps and lengths the same for all files?

Comment: when you read the csv if you specify the cols and data types that will improve performance, but it depends on your work flow, whats the end goal ? if its some form of aggregation then using a distrubuted frame work like Dash may be better.

Comment: I tried dask but it always show distributed.nanny - WARNING - Worker exceeded 95% memory budget. Restarting

Answer (score 1):

this code will combine all the csv files if the files in the same path.

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

dir = Path("../relevant_directory")

df = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in dir.glob("*.csv"))
df = pd.concat(df)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to merge them by ['date','name'], not simple combine the files.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

dir = '../relevant_directory/'

first = True
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk(dir):
for f in files:
    file = str(folder)+str(f)
    if file.split('.')[-1] == 'csv':
        if first:
            data = pd.read_csv(file)
            first = False
        else:
            df = pd.read_csv(file)
            data = pd.merge(data, df, on=['date', 'name'])
```